# Bash: Check json response and write to a file if string exists

Tags: json, bash, curl, jq

I curl an endpoint for a json response and write the response to a file. 
So far I've got a script that:

1). does the curl if the file does not exist and
2). else sets a variable

```
#!/bin/bash
instance="server1"
curl=$(curl -sk https://my-app-api.com | python -m json.tool)
json_response_file="/tmp/file"

if [ ! -f ${json_response_file} ] ; then
  ${curl} > ${json_response_file}
  instance_info=$(cat ${json_response_file})
 else
  instance_info=$(cat ${json_response_file})
fi
```

The problem is, the file may exist with a bad response or is empty. 
Possibly using bash until, I'd like to

(1). check (using JQ) that a field in the curl response contains $instance and only then write the file.

(2). retry the curl XX number of times until the response contains $instance

(3). write the file once the response contains $instance

(4). set the variable instance_info=$(cat ${json_response_file}) when the above is done correctly.

I started like this... then got stuck...

```
until [[ $(/usr/bin/jq --raw-output '.server' <<< ${curl}) = $instance ]]
do
```

Comment: does your conditional not work, or is this a problem figuring out how to implement the logic?

Comment: And why do you need `python -m json.tool` when you have `jq`?

Comment: its a problem trying to figure out the logic. I don't really need python -m json.tool.

Comment: btw, using `${foo}` adds no value over `$foo` when not parameterizing the expansion or doing string concatenation, but using `"$foo"` over `$foo` or `${foo}` would significantly decrease your exposure to bugs. See http://shellcheck.net/ for automated checking on that class of issue.

Comment: ...btw, since your actual bugs don't have anything to do with the curl, jq, or json-related parts of the question, I'm not sure that the tags actually make sense here; this doesn't need a curl export or a jq expert.

Comment: BTW, note that storing fetch results into a shell variable in memory is safe in present circumstances, that's true only because that result is JSON so we know it can't possibly contain any NULs. If it were binary data, `content=$(curl ...)` would corrupt any content containing NULs, either by removing the NUL characters or truncating at the first one (depending on your exact shell version).

Comment: Noted re your point "$foo". I'll try your suggestion below - thank you.

Comment: Since you're using `/tmp`, note the warnings in the current answer's comments about security impact -- think about what happens if some joker creates a symlink to `/etc/passwd` named `/tmp/file` and you run this script as root.

Comment: Shouldn't `${curl} > {$json_response_file}` be `echo "$curl" > $json_response_file`? Your code will try to execute the JSON response as a command.

Comment: @Barmar, ...well, part of the problem here is that the original code was reusing the same response rather than actually re-polling every "retry".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I see that in your answer. I don't see what that has to do with this question about the OP's basic syntax error.

Comment: I don't see this as a question about a syntax error, but a "what would appropriate flow control constructs for this use case be?" -- see my very first comment-thread question, and response to same. Where's the syntax error at hand?

Comment: ...which is to say that I might retitle this to something more like "polling until a condition is met in bash", to make it more generic / helpful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One sane implementation might look something like this:

```
retries=10
instance=server1
response_file=filename

# define a function, since you want to run this code multiple times
# the old version only ran curl once and reused that result
fetch() { curl -sk https://my-app-api.com; }

instance_info=
for (( retries_left=retries; retries_left > 0; retries_left-- )); do
  content=$(fetch)
  server=$(jq --raw-output '.server' <<<"$content")
  if [[ $server = "$instance" ]]; then
    # Writing isn't atomic, but renaming is; doing it this way makes sure that no
    # incomplete response will ever exist in response_file.  If working in a directory
    # like /tmp where others users may have write, use $(mktemp) to create a tempfile with
    # a random name to avoid security risk.
    printf '%s\n' "$content" >"$response_file.tmp" \
      && mv "$response_file.tmp" "$response_file"
    instance_info=$content
    break
  fi
done
[[ $instance_info ]] || { echo "ERROR: Giving up after $retries retries" >&2; }
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked a treat. Now i'll go away and make sure i understand your code. Thanks again

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have any questions -- I can provide references for most of the practices used here. The function encapsulation, for instance, is covered in BashFAQ #50: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: ...some of the others, like preferring `printf` over `echo` when handling externally-provided data, are a bit more obscure -- see the APPLICATION USAGE section of the POSIX spec for `echo`, http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html, if curious.